# The weird setting values of formAction cross browsers

Tags: javascript, html, browser

The formAction attribute of element like input is supported by IE10+, FF, Chrome... When for some reason i reset it to null:

```
// in html
<input id="aa" type="submit" />
// in script
var aa = document.getElementById("aa");
console.log(aa.formAction); // ""
aa.formAction = null;
console.log(aa.formAction);
//"null" in IE10
// "" in Chrome
// "http://currentdomain/currentfolder/null" in Firefox
```

It seems the chrome reset the null value to empty string, and Firefox and IE just change it to string(while Firefox remember it should be a url).
Besides, if set its value to "null", the chrome will return just as same as Firefox.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Actually why you are trying to get `formAction` property value from input field?

Comment: @musefan post here as a mark, and i wonder is there any other different values between get and set in dom attribute via browsers

Comment: @jamesli: So you do not have a question then?

Comment: @KristianVitozev in the project code, we use a multi-tabs form, which submit either to default action urls, or prevent and do some ajax handles when user toggle tabs. so get its value like to check the current logic.